# Moving data Postgres to MySQL using PHP/Laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, laravel-5

I'm using:

- A local Postgres DB
- Laravel 5 with a MySQL DB also local
- Postgres DB contains the table structure from OTRS - with over 91.000 rows on the table "tickets"

I needed to move the data from one DB to the other. What I did was compile a big query that united all the data I needed and run it in a PHP script I created inside the Laravel structure. Then I iterated through the results using Eloquent to insert into MySQL. I know it's terrible but I had to remove the memory and time limits for PHP in order to do this and though it took a really long time, it worked!

Right now I realized I missed something, I need to rerun a similar query (results in the same number of rows), but this time to just add one field on the MySQL DB.

My question is, how can I optimize this process? I'm thinking of using chunks but I don't know how to that.

To clarify:

- MySql's Tickets table contains 91397 rows and 5 columns
- Postgres Tickets table also has 91397 rows and 6 columns
- I created a migration on Laravel (MySQL) that added the extra column (though it's empty)

It's probably easier if I show you the code I have.

[link](http://pastebin.com/jGR4Tcxt)

Comment: Do you want to add a column to an existing schema using Laravel?

Comment: @AliGajani I'll update the post to clarify.

Comment: Since these are both on your machine, is it a one time move?  Or are you developing a repeatable process for moving the data using Eloquent?

Comment: @Stradas both actually. There's a production DB in a remote server. Upon realizing this I adapted my code so I wouldn't fetch all 90k rows but only the last 100. Whenever I deploy this it will sync from it's last known id and "catching up to speed" with the remote production server.

Answer (score 3):

You can use eloquent to do this. Here's how I'd do (untested, may need some tuning):

Set up both DB connections in the `config\database.php`.
 Make two models for the same resource (you can use only one model but I rather not), I'll name them `M1` and `M2`, with different connection attribute. To do this create an attribute inside the model: `protected $connection = 'connection_name'`.

So basically:

```
class M1 extends Model {
   protected $connection = 'connection_name';
   protected $table = 'table_name';
   protected $guarded = [];
```

Same for M2 with a different `$connection`.

Now in your controller method or wherever you're executing your code, you can chunk queries using eloquent:

```
//assuming you are transferring M1's db to M2's

M1::chunk(200, function($m1s)  //if you wanna use only one model, this should be M1::on('connection-name')->chunk(...
{
   foreach ($m1s as $m1)
   {
      $m2 = new M2();
      //this does not copy model-specific attributes like $connection
      $m2->fill( $m1->getAttributes() );  
      $m2->save();
   }
});
```

I think this does the job, can you test this?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will post some feedback once I can test this.

Comment: what if one of the databases has a different table structure?

Comment: I don't think it would matter. If it's a different table name, just set the `table` string. If there are columns that don't exist, eloquent will ignore them.

Comment: it's not just different table names. The first and heaviest table containts foreign keys where I'd be more interested in the content itself. So instead of saying "user_id" = 23; I'd rather have "user"=Mark Twain for example. I'm doing this through a rather complex SQL statement.

Comment: You would have to do that column by column using eloquent. Like: `$m2->user = UserOnOtherDB::find( $m1->user_id ->name)`. Attributes that are the same will be automatically filled, you just fill the ones you need.